# Feelings while meditating

Tags: meditation

During deep meditation, I start to feel waves of some sort of energy that's hard to explain, the best analogy I can find is "an electrostatic feeling, like an aurora borealis" around the head, and sometimes the body too. The deeper the state, the more intense. Sometimes it gets so intense I have to pause, but it is still a powerful and beautiful moment.

Do you have similar experiences?

Comment: This may be a "polling" question.

Comment: Waves of light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a classical account of [priti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%ABti) and [sukha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukha) in the first or second [dhyana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhyana_in_Buddhism). Enjoy these feelings while they appear, try not to get attached to them (which is basically impossible...) and continue to practice.

With time, these sensations will gradually decline, and give way to even deeper states of dhyana, which will come with their own, but different types of pleasures.

For additional accounts and sometimes vivid descriptions of similar experiences please see:

- [Kamalashila's take](https://kamalashila.co.uk/dhyana) on dhyanas with a detailed description of priti and sukha. His book [Buddhist Meditation](https://www.amazon.com/-/es/gp/product/1907314091) is even a bit more detailed.
- Daniel Ingram's book [Mastering the Core Teachings of the Buddha (MCTB)](https://www.mctb.org/mctb2/table-of-contents/) chapter 27, even though he is quite a bit controversial.
- Check the comments on page 2 of the [Wildmind page on Anapanasati](https://www.wildmind.org/mindfulness/one/comment-page-2)

Comment: Pïti describes quite well what I experience, at least in the 3 first levels. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That's mu.  In Zen, we'd say that you are just beginning to touch your true nature.  I'm hesitant to say what will happen from here on out - I don't want to prompt you into expectation - but the short of it is, the intensity of this experience will continue to intensify.  Eventually you might want to do something.  If you get to that point, you really should start working with a teacher otherwise your progress will plateau.  It might even be a good idea to start looking for one now.

Answer (score 0):

I have felt similar.   I suggest the reading below.  I have found this site to be a great help to me.  The link below is a text version of an audio also available on the site as part of the **Basic Collection** of audios.

Note that this site is in the Theravada tradition if that makes a difference to you.

https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/GatherRound/Section0079.html